# Remove specific cell from a dataset in r

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a data set like:

```
   A              B                              C
   hello          Radiation therapy              NA
   Hello1         hello2 for neurology           hello3 radiation
```

and many more rows.

Now i intend to remove all the text after "for" like for "neurology" and also all the text containing "radiation". So i am expecting the output to be:

```
   A              B                            C
   hello          therapy                      NA
   Hello1         hello2                       hello3
```

Answer (score 0):

Example dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(B = c("Radiation therapy", "hello2 for neurology"))
```

Then the code to sub out the strings you want from the B column of the dataframe:

```
df$B <- gsub("Radiation | for.*", "", df$B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
dat <-
structure(list(A = c("hello", "Hello1"), B = c("Radiation therapy", 
"hello2 for neurology"), C = c(NA, "hello3 radiation")), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")

dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) gsub("radiation|for.*", "", x, ignore.case = TRUE))
dat
       A        B       C
1  hello  therapy    <NA>
2 Hello1  hello2  hello3
```